# ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am updating my multi-module spring boot app from Java 8 to Java 11, when I compile and run I have the next error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean 
with name 'useCaseConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'recordRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recordRepositoryAdapter' defined in class path resource [com/grupoasv/ifuner/configuration/RepositoryAdapterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.grupoasv.ifuner.core.application.boundary.repository.IRecordRepository]: Factory method 'recordRepositoryAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1404)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
at com.grupoasv.ifuner.IfunerApplication.main(IfunerApplication.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recordRepositoryAdapter' defined in class path resource [com/grupoasv/ifuner/configuration/RepositoryAdapterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.grupoasv.ifuner.core.application.boundary.repository.IRecordRepository]: Factory method 'recordRepositoryAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.grupoasv.ifuner.core.application.boundary.repository.IRecordRepository]: Factory method 'recordRepositoryAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at com.grupoasv.ifuner.configuration.RepositoryAdapterConfiguration.recordRepositoryAdapter(RepositoryAdapterConfiguration.java:457)
at com.grupoasv.ifuner.configuration.RepositoryAdapterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ba45a9.CGLIB$recordRepositoryAdapter$33(<generated>)
at com.grupoasv.ifuner.configuration.RepositoryAdapterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ba45a9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ddd4bcbb.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
at com.grupoasv.ifuner.configuration.RepositoryAdapterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ba45a9.recordRepositoryAdapter(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.Service
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 53 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I try with adding this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And many more dependencies, I think that is something relationship with JavaEE modules and Corba by Java 11 update, but I try other answers on stack overflow, but nothing works, any idea?

Comment: May I ask you about the version of Spring Boot you're using in your project?

Answer (score -1):

Try this site

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.3.1/source-code

Download the jaxws-api.jar and add it to your lib folder. Then try to run...

Comment: He should add it as a maven dependency not download it himself.

Comment: I definitely argue against this approach. Based on the Question, Maven is used to handle dependencies.